# Django add an underscore in Foreign key field, is there a way to remove it?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I defined a field role, for a User Model which is foreign key for UserRole table

```
role = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
```

When I run migrate command, it creates tables in Mysql DB with all fields but foreign key has an underscore in it -

```
role_id
```

I need to follow a convention of having all field names without the underscore. So can someone guide how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change this by specifying `db_column` ([django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#database-representation))

```
role = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, db_column='roleid')
```